# How to make height constraint to view in tableviewcell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have tableview, 1 cell and 1 view in cell. 
Constraints for view: 
top, right, bottom, left equal to superview
height = 250
And there is an error.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 250
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}


}

extension ViewController {
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let view = UIView()

    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.contentView.addSubview(view)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
    view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.superview!.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    return cell
}
}
```

I expected no error messages, but here there are.

> 2019-10-21 18:05:41.265530+0300 ffffffffff[73908:5577499]
>   [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>     Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
>   you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
>   figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
>
> ```
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d9ea30 UIView:0x7feb2a700c00.height == 250   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d9e2b0 V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7feb2a700c00]   (active, names:
> '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7feb2a5050b0 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d9e1c0 UIView:0x7feb2a700c00.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7feb2a5050b0.bottom   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002db8b90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'
> UITableViewCellContentView:0x7feb2a5050b0.height == 250.333 (active)>" )
> ```
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints
>   to catch this in the debugger. The methods in the
>   UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in
>    may also be helpful.